# Is there a plugin for uploading files such as PDF files?

Tags: plugins, pdf

I want to put my lecturers for my students as PDF files in my wordpress, is it possible?

Comment: Please explain why you don't want to use the regular upload button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible.
File upload is a default feature of WordPress. You  don't need to use plugins for this.

Read [how to upload files in WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Uploading_Files).